# Why don't the crew of Voyager ever talk about building replacement shuttles?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

After watching a few seasons of Star Trek Voyager, it seems like crashing shuttle crafts becomes somewhat of a theme. You quickly get to the point where you start to wonder how many shuttles can fit in the shuttle bay of such a "small" starship", especially with Neelix's large shuttle sharing the space.

The accepted answer to this question: [How many shuttles does Voyager have, not including The Delta Flyer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121033/how-many-shuttles-does-voyager-have-not-including-the-delta-flyer) determines that Voyager had to have had,

> [...] up to 8 shuttles at any given time, with up to 17 built during
>   the show's run.

So if crashing shuttle crafts was a regular occurrence, and the crew of voyager had to construct at least 17 new shuttle crafts to replace all the one's they had destroyed. How come you never here the captain or the crew talking about constructing new crafts? Or finding components and materials to build crafts? Or even salvaging what's left of a crashed shuttle so they can use it as spare parts to build the next one?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but at some point building the Delta Flyer (Tom's fancy shuttle) was a big part of several episodes.

Comment: Because the people who work in the shuttlebay aren't important enough to get their own episode.

Answer (score 13):

The very simple (out-of-universe) answer is that the show focuses on a small but vital subset of the ship's crew; the command staff and their lives and loves. We spend at least 70% of our time on various [pre-built sets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4sX6hEmnik) like shuttles, holodeck, bridge, corridors, sickbay, etc, with the remainder of the time spent [on location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_shooting).

What we don't do, except [very rarely](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lower_Decks_(episode)), is spend time with the [little people](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/407.htm) who actually make the ship go. We don't see the programmers programming things, nor the engineers cleaning the warp manifolds. We don't see the Torpedo maintenance staff maintaining torpedoes, nor the probe loading staff loading probes. In short, we almost never see the guts of the ship, nor the hardworking peons within. This evidently includes the shuttle bay staff whose job it is to maintain (and if needs be, replace) the shuttles that the Command Staff have managed to blow up, usually as a result of their gross incompetence, this week.

---

The closest we come, in-universe, is when **the Command Crew decide that they need to build a shuttle.** We learn that Paris has been agitating for them to upgrade their crappy Class-2 shuttles for quite some time. They evidently have parts in storage for just such an eventuality.

> **PARIS:** *Let's face it, Class-two shuttles just don't cut it in the Delta quadrant. We've needed something bigger and better since we got
> here. It's time we built it!*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** ***Tom, we've been through this I don't know how many times.** We all appreciate your enthusiasm.*

and

> **PARIS:** *We could replicate the alloys and the new design components, **use spare parts from storage.** If we worked around the
> clock we could have it up and running inside a week.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Voy: Extreme Risk](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/503.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: I noticed you didn't mention the name of the shulttle/ship they ended up building ("The Delta Flyer")