# How many shuttles does the Discovery normally carry?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

I know that all combined the Enterprise and Discovery had "over 200 vessels" at the Battle at Boreth, and some apparently were drones. The picture below shows a steady stream of shuttles leaving the bay. What is her normal complement of shuttles?

[image: Discovery launching shuttles and drones]

Comment: And is it more or less than [the 17 or so that *Voyager* destroyed, but still had replacements for](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121033/13217)?